# creating mongodb connection in php

Tags: php, json, mongodb, internal-server-error

I want to open a connection to mongodb in php but I get internal server error. this is my code:

```
<?php
        header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
        ini_set("display_errors", "1"); error_reporting(E_ALL);

        $m = new MongoClient( "${my_username}:${my_password}@mongodb://my_host:my_port" );
        $db = $m->my_database;
        $collection = $db->my_table;

        $result = $collection->find();

        foreach($result as $entry) {
            echo $entry["name"] . "\n";
            }
?>
```

Everything with with private info has been replaced with `my_*`. From this code i get 500 Internal server error. Where is it going wrong?

Comment: Can you provide any more information about the error that you receive?

Comment: i dont know how to access the error logs and where to find them. Would you say the code is good or not?

Comment: I have the feeling that your compilation of PHP does not include the MongoDB extension - but I have no way of knowing for sure without seeing error logs.

Comment: That is a very logical reason, matter of fact.. i think that is the problem. Cuz I run on host company, iPage.